# Target specific line in text/data file after a certain point

Tags: python

So I have some data in a file which includes both text and data.
For example a snippet of it could look like this:

```
Structure: PTV
Plan: CT
Course: 900
Volume [cm³]: 107.2
Dose Cover.[%]: 100.0
Sampling Cover.[%]: 99.9
Min Dose [%]: 90.2
Max Dose [%]: 104.9
Mean Dose [%]: 100.0
Modal Dose [%]: 99.7
Median Dose [%]: 100.1
STD [%]: 1.7
```

Before that there is a lot of other stuff that I don't need, and also after. Basically I want to target the line saying `Volume [cm³]: 107.2` and use that value for calculations etc. However, since there are different structures in the data files, this text/pattern/snippet is repeated for different structures, so I just can't say: "Use the data input where it says Volume [cm³]" since that occurs a lot of places, AND they are not necessarily in the same order always as well. So the one I need might be number 2 in some file, and 4 in another.

So how would I go about targeting the `Volume [cm³]: 107.2` line AFTER the line saying `Structure: PTV` or whatever name is needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear. Since you tagged it as python, I suppose you are looking for a solution in this language. What you need are probably [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Python has a built-in module named [re](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html).

```
import re
with open('yourdata', 'r') as f:
    str = f.read()

pattern = re.compile("Volume \[([^]]*)\]: ([0-9.]*)")
re.findall(pattern, str)
```

This will give you a list of (unit, value):

```
Out[29]: [('cm³', '107.2')]
```

Comment: Ah, yes, it was of course Python language I needed to do it in. But that indeed gave me the volume values, thank you :D